# Vue Route BroeadCrumbs Value is refreshing page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Today I discovered very unusual bug on my project. I'm trying to show breadcrumbs value in my layout, but every time when I import `route.meta.breadcrumbs.value` in template, it's rerendering component, and every request is doubled.

So what do I have.
In main.ts file is casual.

```
import App from '@/layout/App.vue'
const app: App = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

So in App.vue, I have renderer for breadcrumbs and it's like

```
<div>
 {{$t(route.meta.breadcrumbs.value)}}
</div>
```

And this is how I define breadcrumbs in other components:

```
route.meta.breadcrumbs.value = 'asda'
```

So it's simple as it is, when I write only `route.meta.breadcrumbs` without `value` it will not refresh the page.
Have in mind that this problem is causing only when I refresh that page, if I click on a vue router to get to this page, everything is fine, that is why it's unusual problem.

Anyone had similar problems?

Edit: The problem is definitely coming from `route.meta.breadcrumbs.value = 'asda'` but I still don't have fix